# Jquery events dont work in/after backbone rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view which renders form inputs.

After rendering I want to bind some events on the inputs, for example, numeric formats like

`$('input').numeric();`

or color all the inputs like

`$('input').css('background-color', 'red');`

But these events do not work.

So this is a view:

```
App.Views.StockPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    /* some things */
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    /* rendering form */
    this.format(); // to call some formatting jquery events
    return this;
},
format: function() {
    console.log('check'); // just for callback check
    $('input').css('background-color', 'red');
}
});
```

So console properly writes 'check' but the next event does NOT work.
What i do wrong? pls, help, im novice in js/backbone.

Comment: Can you show us some of your rendering code?  I'm just guessing but, you might be trying to `format` before the `input` is on the page.

Comment: yes, @jungy, you're, right.

Comment: @KamilDavudov Great to hear!  I would also recommend passing `this.el` to your jQuery calls so, it doesn't traverse through the whole DOM each time.  For example, `$('input', this.el).css(...)`

Comment: @jungy [`this.$('input')`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) would be more idiomatic than `$('input, this.el)`, probably easier to read at a glance as well.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes that is absolutely correct

Comment: `console.log(this.$('input').length)` if it's zero something wrong with your form render.

Answer (score 0):

I appended then() event to rendering function and active jquery event just after rendering. So jquery waits for the whole rendering and just after that binds its events.